# Let $y = \frac{x^2 \ln(x)}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

a) Find $y'$

b)Find the value of $x$ which the given curve has a horizontal tangent.

**my attempt**

**I)** $y' = \frac{x^2 \ln(x)}{2}$

$$\frac {2(y'(x^2\ln(x))}{2^2}$$

$x^2\cdot y'(\ln(x)) + \ln(x)*y'(x^2)$

$x^2*1/x \ + \ln(x)\cdot 2x$

$y' = 2(\ x+2x\ln(x))/4$

**II)** $$y' = \frac{x^2}{4}$$

$y' = \frac{4\cdot2x}{16}$

$y' = \frac{x}{2}$

**a)**$$y'  \ = \ \frac {2( x+2x\ln(x))}{4}- \frac{x}{2} $$

for b) I don't know.

Comment: You might want to simplify your derivative first.

Comment: Solve for y' = 0.  x can't be 0 as ln(0) isn't defined.  So divide by x and solve for 2(1 + 2\ln (x))/4)  - 1/2=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y = \frac{x^2 \ln(x)}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}$, then $y'=\frac12 (2x\ln x+\frac{ x^2}x)-\frac{2x}4=x\ln x$ since the polynomial terms cancel.

Horizontal lines have gradient $0$, and therefore any tangent line to the curve that is horizontal will have gradient $0$, the same gradient as the curve at that point. Hence we look for them when we set $y'=0$.

Ie: $x\cdot \ln x=0$. Note that both functions ($x$ and $\ln x$) are zero exactly once, so it is enough to check where these functions are zero. For the first one, the obvious one is $x=0$, but note that the logarithm is not defined at $0$, so this answer is discarded. Next, $\ln x=0 \iff x=1$, so this is our only zero.

Comment: I didn't understand how you got to this result for y', I did the the quocient rule for the terms and I didn't get the same result.

Comment: @hjx Why would you use the quotient rule?  It is a product. $y' ~{=(\tfrac {x^2\ln x}2 -\tfrac {x^2}4)'\\= (\frac{x^2}4)'\cdot(2 \ln x- 1) + (\frac{x^2}4)\cdot(2\ln x-1)' \\ =(\frac x 2)\cdot(2\ln x-1)+(\frac{x^2}4)(2x^{-1}) \\= x\ln x }$

Comment: I thought I should use the quociente rule, because x^2lnx/2 is a division, but as 2 is as constant I didn't know I should see it as a 1/2 * x^2lnx, thanks man.

Comment: @hjx your result is identical to $x\log x\quad$. Try to simplify $y'  \ = \ \dfrac {2( x+2x\ln(x))}{4}- \dfrac{x}{2}=\dfrac{2x+4x\log x-2x}{4}=x\log x$

Comment: @Raffaele thanks

Answer (score 1):

$y = \frac{x^2 \ln(x)}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}$

$y' = x\ln(x) + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x}{2}$

---

$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$ and $g(x) = \ln(x)$

$y = f(x)g(x)$

by product rule,

$y = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = x\ln(x) + \frac{x^2}{2}(\frac{1}{x})$

now simply subtract the derivative of $\frac{x^2}{4}$ to get your original $y'$

---

to find the value of x for horizontal tangent, set $y' = 0$ and solve for $x$